# DatabaseError: invalid ObjectId

Tags: python, mongodb

I receive this error each time I run `python manage.py syncdb`

```
DatabaseError: AutoField (default primary key) values must be strings
representing an ObjectId on MongoDB (got u'1' instead).
Please make sure your SITE_ID contains a valid ObjectId string.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, your question is not well phrased - did you read the guidelines on asking a good question?   As it stands, you are unlikely to receive a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem some months back a simple fix it to give a SITE id.

```
python ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> Site().save()
>>> Site.objects.all()[0].id
u'qwelknqweklnqwekn13eo13'
```

Comment: After running the above code in shell i get this message

DeprecationWarning: A() queries are deprecated as of 0.5 and will be removed in 0.6.

how do i fix it?
  DeprecationWarning)

Comment: As its a deprecation warning, i think it must have generated the Side ID. Can you go ahead and run the next steps. If you have error can you paste the error ?